# JavaScript in CEWP does not execute

Tags: javascript, content-editor-web-part, json

After putting a small script together and pasting it into the Content Editor Web part all my breakpoints show the following warning in IE 8's debugger: "The breakpoint is not valid. No executable code is associated with this line".

I realize that the CEWP is not the most ideal environment for executing JavaScript. Generally linked files are better however this same issue has occurred even when I have linked the CEWP to a script file. The script is as follows:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/code_lib/excanvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}}; </script>
<script language="javascript" src="/code_lib/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/code_lib/jquery.jqplot.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/code_lib/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/code_lib/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="/code_lib/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/code_lib/jquery.jqplot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script language="javascript" src="/code_lib/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var stringURL = https://mydomain.com/Sandbox/bitest/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Produce 

$.getJSON(stringURL, function(data){
    quantityOneArray=[];
        $(data).find("z\\:row").each(function(i, result) {
            quantityOneArray[i] = parseFloat($(this).attr("ows_Quantity"));
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

It's possible that I messed up the syntax in my code or made another obvious error.

I am linking in many JavaScript libraries to ultimately create a chart with the pulled JSON data. This script is designed to run in IE7 hence the JSON2 call and the console script in the head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to place quotes around the url and a semicolon:
`var stringURL = "http://mydomain.com/Sandbox/bitest/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Produce";`

Comment: Any advice on a good IDE to develop JavaScript in? I find I constantly make simple mistakes like this because I am using NotePad++. It's a great tool, but it doesn't catch syntax errors as I make them. It may be that I'm green, but visual web developer 2010 doesn't seem to work very well and I can't quite understand how to make a simple script in Eclipse without creating some monstrous new project.

Comment: Generally I just use visual studio, that catches some stuff, but usually I just try to be careful and use chrome when doing javascript stuff. In Chrome the javascript errors are much more useful and you can edit actively.

Comment: I recommend visual studio as well. You can make your files open in VS by default within SharePoint designer if you right-click and use "open with program..." before selecting "Visual Studio version selector".